# Why does eclipse not recognize Java nature of a multimodule maven project if name template is added to it?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I've a springboot project which is organized as multiple modules. I'm using Eclipse 2019-06 (version 4.12) with jdk 1.8 update 131 and apache maven 3.3.9 version.

While importing the project using *Maven -> Existing maven projects -> select all project and module level poms->click on finish button*, it does the import successfully.

I can view the child modules as separate projects that can be individually run by right clicking on them to project workspace. JUnit tests successfully run using *right click -> Run As -> JUnit test.*

But if i include a name template while importing the project, the child modules are not recognized even though I select all the child poms also while importing.

Java files show empty J which indicates that it doesn't recognize the Java nature. Because of this, I am unable to run *JUnit* tests and *ctrl+click* to navigate to a method or class is also not working.

In both cases, the contents of .project remain the same:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>my-springboot-app</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

I tried the following steps as suggested in other stackoverflow threads:

1. **Manually edit the above xml to add Java nature tags along with maven.**
   This didnt help as somehow it started showing the corresponding child projects as packages instead of modules in the project/package explorer.
2. **Convert the project to a faceted one.** This started showing up more errors as Java nature of the project was still not recognized by maven.
3. **Use mvn eclipse:clean or remove.project file from the code location and then use mvn eclipse:eclipse**. This just recreated the .project file and didn't help for importing the child projects successfully.

Note that eclipse builds the project while importing it when I do not import the project specifying a name template for it but not otherwise.

It would be nice if someone could let me know if that is a problem with *m2e plugin* itself and that whether I should use another plugin instead.

*Eclipse 4.12* comes with *m2e pre-installed* with it. I thought of using a name template instead of switching workspaces which could take time so that 2-3 flavours of my code can be seen in the same *eclipse workspace*.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the dialog where you're adding the name template?

Comment: @chrylis -thanks for asking that. Your question prompted me to relook into the name template format which I use and I got a workaround now. Earlier, i was specifying a custom name as my name template. but now, when i use [artifactid]-02 for example, the next project is imported successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with custom name being used as name template. When I use any of the available options like [groupid].[artifactid]-version or just the [artifactid]-version, m2e successfully imports the project. I saw some errors in the earlier project with respect to import class resolution but they went away when i closed unrelated projects in workspace.